# Managing certificates on CentOS

Tags: centos, certificate

How can I reliably check if a certificate has been installed on CentOS 5.5? I've done some research on my own but suggested methods like calling certutil have all failed. What I have done is searched the disk for anything containing the expected file name or the .crt extension but I don't thinks this is a reliable test.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The certificates on CentOS usually kept under `/etc/pki`.